# is it possible to connect from Windows (client) to ubuntu (server)?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, remote-desktop

is it possible to connect ubuntu (without a graphical desktop, there's just the terminal) using remote desktop connection of Ms Windows? But when I connect there will be a graphical interface on that. Thank you in advance

Comment: If you're just connecting to Ubuntu's terminal, how come you don't just ssh into it?

Comment: What I want, connect with graphical desktop in the client (Windows) and if direct in the server (ubuntu) without, is it possible !? Not juste ssh, thanks.

Comment: Not with remote desktop, no. there are some other solutions like nx or vnc that can be set up on ubuntu, and they have windows client software. I believe you can also start a windowed environment inside an ssh session (though I haven't done that in a decade). for any of these to work, you would have to install a desktop environment on the ubuntu box, and then configure it to not start automatically, so you have a text terminal on the server, but a graphical environment over a remote connection, if you connect via ssh and start it when you want to connect.

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much, it's a solution ^^